# onCreate(...) is called twice after the device is rotated

Tags: android

I have a question about rotating the Android device.  My code logs a static and non-static attribute in onCreate(...).

```java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static int sn;
    int n;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        sn++;
        n++;

        Log.i("onCreate", String.format("sn=%d n=%d", sn, n));
    }
}
```

The screen orientation is portrait. When I first ran the code, I got:

```
onCreate(): sn=1 n=1
```

After I rotated the screen to landscape, I got:

```
onCreate(): sn=2 n=1
```

After I rotated the screen again to portrait, I got:

```
onCreate(): sn=3 n=1
onCreate(): sn=4 n=1
```

My questions are:

1. How can I prevent onCreate(...) to be called twice when the device is rotated back to portrait?
2. How can I save the value of non-static variable when the device is rotated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whenever the screen orientation is changed, that Activity is destroyed and a new activity starts by `onCreate()` method.
so every time you rotate the screen that activity will be destroyed and a new activity starts by `onCreate()` method.
You can save Non Static member by overriding `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle b)` method.
Android calls this method whenever the screen is rotated, and that given bundle b would be passed to `oncreate(Bundle b)` from which you can extract your non `static` member.

Comment: I overrided `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` but it was not called when I rotated my emulator.

Comment: you may not have properly ovverided the method, it is called just before onPause().

Comment: @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle1){            
  super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle1);
  Log.i(tag,"inside onSaveInstanceState");
  bundle1.putInt("variable n",n);
  bundle1.putInt("sn",sn);
  }

Comment: I know the reason why I cannot see my log message in `onSaveInstanceState(...).  It is because the `tag` parameter in Log.i(tag, msg)` is too long.  Thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 32):

This is a known issue in the emulator (see the discussion [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2423)). It's not a bug, but it is an issue for many people going back years. As I understand it, the basic problem is that your activity is restarted twice when it goes into portrait mode because the emulator is handling two configuration changes separately: the orientation change itself and the deactivation of the keyboard. It doesn't happen in the other direction because there isn't a configuration change event corresponding to activation of the keyboard. (I find this strange, but evidently this is the desired behavior for some reason.)

In any event, the solution seems to be this to add this to your activity manifest declaration:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

If you actually require those changes to load new resources, you can manually handle it in onConfigurationChanged.

Comment: +1; interesting. I'd never even noticed it was called twice (or if it should matter if it is).

Comment: +1: noticed it on the emulator but never bothered me testing with a real device (going back to 1.6/2.x days).  Haven't relied on the emulator since.

Comment: I had to use this to cover all bases: `keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize`

Comment: android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" I've added. thanks.

Comment: Not only for emulator, its also behaving the same on real device, as well as, configChanges not working out for me :(

Answer (score 3):

Don't know about the `onCreate` issue; those calls come from the OS.

Non-static ("instance") variables should be saved in the `instanceState`; that's what it's for. See [posts like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state) that sum it up, or most basic Android tutorials that discuss the application lifecycle.

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState(...)` is not called when I rotate the emulator. And `onPause()` does not accept any `Bundle`. Where can I save the `instanceState`?

Comment: @user639616 Are you sure? It should be, because the activity is destroyed and recreated.

Comment: I overrided `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and log some message. But I cannot see the log message.

Comment: I know the reason why I cannot see my log message in `onSaveInstanceState(...).  It is because the `tag` parameter in Log.i(tag, msg)` is too long.  Thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you rotate screen activity will be recreated -- This is concept of android.

But in your case when activity recreated static value will be retained..  while `non static` will be  reinitialized... So you are getting `n=1` always...

If you really want to retain that non static value then go [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). In this you can retain all values you need until user clears data....

else simply make `non static` to `static` which will solve your probably I guess

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple: you can override the method onConfigurationChanged() in your code.

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    }
```

So now your non static variable will not affected, because in this time your Activity is not destroyed and not a new activity starts by onCreate() method.

Comment: Do I still have to set the attribute `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` in the manifest file?

Comment: it IS required!!! onConfigurationChanged is called ONLY IF you set the attribute android:configChanges !

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in your activity inside AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

From [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

> "`singleTask`" and "`singleInstance`" activities can only begin a task.
>   They are always at the root of the activity stack. Moreover, the
>   device can hold only one instance of the activity at a time — only one
>   such task.
>
> A "`singleInstance`" activity, on the other hand, permits no other
>   activities to be part of its task. It's the only activity in the task.
>   If it starts another activity, that activity is assigned to a
>   different task — as if `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` was in the intent.