# Why is element value added twice when iterating firebase database in Kotlin?

Tags: firebase, for-loop, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, duplicates

I'm trying to iterate the `firebase-database` and add its elements to my object. It works, but for some reason I fail to understand, it ads each element twice, the log output showing something like this:

```
TAGZ: DataSnapshot { key = recipeHeaderFirebase, value = Tahini-Oat Cookies } 
TAGZ: DataSnapshot { key = recipeHeaderFirebase, value = Tahini-Oat Cookies }
TAGZ: DataSnapshot { key = recipeHeaderFirebase, value = Chocolate & Cinnamon Cookies }
TAGZ: DataSnapshot { key = recipeHeaderFirebase, value = Chocolate & Cinnamon Cookies }
TAGZ: DataSnapshot { key = recipeHeaderFirebase, value = Sweet Potato Muffin }
TAGZ: DataSnapshot { key = recipeHeaderFirebase, value = Sweet Potato Muffin }
TAGZ: DataSnapshot { key = recipeHeaderFirebase, value = Almond Butter Cookies }
TAGZ: DataSnapshot { key = recipeHeaderFirebase, value = Almond Butter Cookies }
```

The `Firebase-database` structure looks like this (note that I have ignored the other elements for now):

[image: FbDb]

My Kotlin code looks like this:

```
fbdb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
ref = fbdb!!.getReference("cookies")

ref!!.addChildEventListener(object: ChildEventListener {

    override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {
        val children = snapshot!!.children //DIRECT REFERENCE TO CHILD, USED FOR LOOP
        val header = snapshot!!.child("recipeHeaderFirebase")

        for(it in children) {
            var tempRecipe = RecipeTemplate()
            tempRecipe.recipeHeader = header.toString()
            Log.d("TAGZ", tempRecipe.recipeHeader)  //OUTPUT SHOWS DUPLICATE VALUES
            }
        }
    })
```

What am I missing? I successfully retrieve the elements in Xcode using similar code...

***EDIT*** FULL CODE ON REQUEST:

```
package com.healthandchocolate.sjostedtafzelius.healthchocolateandroid

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import com.google.firebase.database.*

class RecipeGridView : AppCompatActivity() {

private var fbdb: FirebaseDatabase? = null
private var ref: DatabaseReference? = null
var recipeArray: MutableList<RecipeTemplate> = mutableListOf()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_grid_view)
    Log.d("TAG", "ON CREATE");

    fbdb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    ref = fbdb!!.getReference("cookies")

    ref!!.addChildEventListener(object: ChildEventListener {

        override fun onChildChanged(snapshot: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {

        }

        override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {
            Log.d("TAG", "ON CHILD MOVED");
        }

        override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot?) {
            Log.d("TAG", "ON CHILD REMOVED");

        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            print(error)
            Log.d("TAG", "ON ERROR");

        }

        override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {
            Log.d("TAGZ", "CALLED")  //keyName of each child

            val children = snapshot!!.children //DIRECT REFERENCE TO CHILD, USED FOR LOOP
            val header = snapshot!!.child("recipeHeaderFirebase")

            for(it in children) {
                var tempRecipe = RecipeTemplate()
                tempRecipe.recipeHeader = header.toString()
                //Log.d("TAGZ", tempRecipe.recipeHeader)  //keyName of each child

                recipeArray.add(tempRecipe)
            }
        }
        }) //END FB CODE
}
}
```

Comment: It seems that the event listener has been called twice

Comment: @csblo Has it? How so? Where?

Comment: Can you publish more of your code ? What IDE you use when the bug appear ?

Comment: Indeed, onChildAdded() is called twice, which my log showed. Question is why and how to prevent it....

Comment: @csblo I added the full code, but there isn't really much more to show. Using Android Studio.

Comment: What did you think about this topic ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032475/oncreate-is-called-twice-after-the-device-is-rotated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171303/discussion-between-johanjohansson-and-csblo).

Answer (score 1):

The Activity is created each time the system route an intent to the instance of current activity. So the function `onCreate` can be called many times.

Each time your function gets called, the callback function you hold for the `addChildEventListener` event is added to the listener. Thereafter, when the event is triggered, the callback function is called as much as it has been linked to the listener before.

In order to prevent this behavior, you can define `android:launchmode:"singleTop"` in your App manifest file in the tag `<activity>`

This allow the system to route the intents to an other function `onNewIntent` instead of `onCreate`

For more information, take a tour on :
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode

I hope this will help.

I try my best to write correct english, so feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to move your code that adds the *ChildEventListener* from onCreate to a function `fun attachValueEventListener()` outside onCreate.

Then attach the listener in onStart method...

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    // add an event listener to watch changes in firebase database
    attachValueEventListener()
}
```

...and detach the listener in onStop

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    // detach the event listener that watches changes in firebase database
    detachValueEventListener()
}

private fun detachValueEventListener() {
    if (mValueEventListener != null) {
        myRef?.removeEventListener(mValueEventListener)
        mValueEventListener = null
    }
}
```

You will also need to declare

```
private var mValueEventListener: ValueEventListener? = null
```